# Tokio broadcast channel gets lots of RecvErr::Lagged in websocket stream with channel size 1

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a program listening to a websocket stream, and use a `tokio::sync::broadcast::channel` with channel size 1 to broadcast the msgs. The msg from websocket will arrive at a rate like this distribution:

```
[5,25,50,75,95,99] // percentile
[7.42400000e+03, 2.48320000e+04, 1.03270400e+06, 8.12652800e+06,+07, 8.18310554e+07] // nano seconds
```

Then I got lots of `RecvErr::Lagged` from broadcast receiver, nearly 20%.

Then I test it with a snippet like:

```
#[tokio::test(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 2)]
async fn test_tokio_broadcast() {
    use spin_sleep;
    env_logger::builder().format_timestamp_millis().init();
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    log::info!("{:?}", args);
    let duration_us: u64 = args[2].parse().unwrap();

    let (tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::broadcast::channel(1);
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            spin_sleep::sleep(Duration::from_micros(duration_us));
            log::info!("send at {}", now_ns());
            tx.send(1).unwrap();
        }
    });
    let mut c: u64 = 0;
    loop {
        let v = rx.recv().await;
        c += 1;
        match v {
            Ok(v) => {
                log::info!("{} normal {}", now_ns(), c);
            }
            Err(err) => {
                match err {
                    RecvError::Closed => {
                        panic!();
                    }
                    RecvError::Lagged(count) => {
                        log::info!("{} lag {} count {}", now_ns(),c, count);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and run it with

```
 RUST_LOG=info cargo test --release test_tokio_broadcast -- 20 --nocapture 2>&1 | tee log
```

I still got a 1% lag rate. Isn't that pretty high without any loads? Why in the websocket case the rate is much higher (it just replace the producer with the websocket stream), How can I improve it? It is the best that broadcast channel can do? Or any replacement.